Continuous map to a connected set
I am trying to solve this problem. I am studying for an exam.
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a connected open set. Given $x_0, y_0 \in \Omega$, show that for every $M > 0$ there exists a continuous map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Omega$ such that $f(0,0) = x_0$ and such that if $||x|| > M$, then $f(x) = y_0$.
I don't even know where to start with this problem. I don't know which theorem to use. Am I supposed to give an explicit $f$ or is it just some existence statement that is needed? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Have you looked at the $n=1$ case for inspiration?

Then I would have $\Omega = (a,b)$ and $x_0, y_0 \in (a,b)$. But how do I use the $|x| > M$ condition to construct a function? This would mean that from some point on in the interval, $f$ would be constant and equal to $y_0$. I guess I could define $f$ by sections, assuming $x_0 < y_0$ and $M$ somehow being a value between $a$ and $b$. Is this the correct approach?

Yes:  draw some pictures.

Take $g: \mathbb R^2 \to [0,1]$ defined as:
$$g(x) = \min(\|\frac xM\|, 1)$$
This is continuous and also $g(x) = 1$ for $\|x\| >M$ and $g(0,0) = 0$. Now an open connected set in $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected, as such for $x_0,y_0 \in \Omega$, choose $\gamma: [0,1] \to \Omega$ a continuous function such that $\gamma(0)=x_0$ and $\gamma(1)=y_0$. Now let $f(x):=\gamma(g(x))$ and you have the function you want since it is the composition of continuous functions.

Great solution and great explanation. Thanks a lot.
